# Calculating mean and covariance of a truncated multivariate Gaussian

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, statistics, normal-distribution

Consider a $d$-dimensional normal random variable with mean vector $\mu$ and covariance matrix $\Sigma$ whose support is truncated to the level-set $D_{r}=\left\{ x\ |\ \left(x-\mu\right)^{\top}\Sigma^{-1}\left(x-\mu\right)\leq r\right\}$. I would like to calculate the mean and covariance matrix of this new distribution. The density is given by

$$f\left(x\ ;\mu,\Sigma,r\right)=\frac{1}{C_{r}}\cdot\frac{1}{\left(2\pi\right)^{\frac{d}{2}}\sqrt{\det\left(\Sigma\right)}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(x-\mu\right)^{\top}\Sigma^{-1}\left(x-\mu\right)\right)\mathbf{1}_{\left\{ \left(x-\mu\right)^{\top}\Sigma^{-1}\left(x-\mu\right)\leq r\right\} }\left(x\right)$$

where the normalization constant is fortunately easy to calculate since $$C_{r}=\int_{D_{r}}\varphi\left(x;\mu,\Sigma\right)dx=\mathbb{P}\left(\left(x-\mu\right)^{\top}\Sigma^{-1}\left(x-\mu\right)\leq r\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(\chi_{d}^{2}\leq r\right)$$ where $\chi_{d}^{2}$ is distributed chi-square with $d$ degrees of freedom. I am pretty sure that due to the symmetry of the truncation the mean of this truncated distribution is simply $\mu$ (correct me if I am wrong) and I am wondering if it is possible to derive a closed form for the covariance matrix.

For simplicity I looked at the case where $\Sigma$ is diagonal and tried writing out the integration for the covariance terms by doing a change of variable to $z=\Sigma^{-\frac{1}{2}}\left(x-\mu\right)$ which in the diagonal case gives $z_{i}=\frac{x_{i}-\mu_{i}}{\sqrt{\Sigma_{ii}}}$. I unfortunately got stuck pretty quickly. Denoting $C_{r}^{'}=\left(C_{r}\left(2\pi\right)^{\frac{d}{2}}\sqrt{\det\left(\Sigma\right)}\right)^{-1}$ we have $$\text{Cov}\left(X_{i},X_{j}\right)=\int\limits _{D_{r}}\left(x_{i}-\mu_{i}\right)\left(x_{j}-\mu_{j}\right)f\left(x\ ;\mu,\Sigma,r\right)dx$$
$$=C_{r}^{'}\int\limits _{D_{r}}\left(x_{i}-\mu_{i}\right)\left(x_{j}-\mu_{j}\right)\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(x-\mu\right)^{\top}\Sigma^{-1}\left(x-\mu\right)\right)dx\\=C_{r}^{'}\int\limits _{D_{r}}\sqrt{\Sigma_{ii}\Sigma_{jj}}z_{i}z_{j}\frac{1}{\det\left(\Sigma^{-\frac{1}{2}}\right)}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}z^{\top}z\right)dz\\=\sqrt{\Sigma_{ii}\Sigma_{jj}}\left(C_{r}\left(2\pi\right)^{\frac{d}{2}}\right)^{-1}\int\limits _{D_{r}}z_{i}z_{j}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}z^{\top}z\right)dz$$

So now the question is basically whether there is a closed form for $$\int\limits _{D_{r}}z_{i}z_{j}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}z^{\top}z\right)dz,\ \ D_{r}=\left\{ z\ |\ z^{\top}z\leq r\right\}$$

**Edit**: it occurs to me that if $\Sigma$ is diagonal then even after truncation there should be no correlation and thus $\text{Cov}\left(X_{i},X_{j}\right)=0$ for $i\neq j$. This means the above integral should evaluate to zero when $i\neq j$ and it would thus suffice to compute the case where $i=j$ which is $$\int\limits _{D_{r}}z_{i}^{2}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}z^{\top}z\right)dz$$

I would very much appreciate help answering this question.

Comment: I would agree with *"due to the symmetry of the truncation the mean of this truncated distribution is simply $μ$"* and with *"if $\Sigma$ is diagonal then even after truncation there should be no correlation and thus $\text{Cov}\left(X_{i},X_{j}\right)=0$ for $i\neq j$"*

Comment: For $\text{Cov}\left(X_{i},X_{i}\right)=\text{Var}\left(X_{i}\right)$ when $\Sigma$ is diagonal, you are effectively truncating the sum of of squares of two independent zero-mean normal random variables, one of which has variance $\sigma^2_{i}$ and the other $\text{trace}(\Sigma)-\sigma^2_{i}$

Comment: @Henry Thank you for the comments!
With regard to the variance in the diagonal case I don't fully understand what you mean, could you elaborate further? If you can provide an expression for the variance that would be extremely helpful.

Comment: What I think I am saying is that to truncate an $d$-dimensional uncorrelated normal distribution, your calculation of each component of the variance can treat it as two-dimensional

Comment: @Henry Hi Henry, thank you again for your reply. I am afraid I still don't understand how to use the information your gave me. Essentially what I really need is a transformation from the parameters $\Sigma$  to the covariance of the truncated distribution. It would suffice for my needs to have this only in the diagonal case. If you can help me solve this I would be very grateful.